# NSButton not callable after CATransform3DMakeTranslation

Tags: swift, nsview, nsbutton, catransform3d, target-action

I have a strange issue never seen on `iOS` but present on `macOS Swift` development.

I have a `NSButton` which is added with an `addSubview` method to a custom `NSView`. The button has a target function. 
It is impossible to click on this button when it's added to the `customView`. If I add it to the global "view" works fine directly.

Any idea why this could be?

```
//Infos View
self.infosView.wantsLayer = true
self.infosView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.darkGray.cgColor

self.view.addSubview(self.infosView)

 //TestButton
let myButtonRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
self.testButton = NSButton.init(frame: myButtonRect)

// !!!!
// this line doesn't work
// !!!!
self.infosView.addSubview(testButton)

// !!!!
// but this line works fine
// !!!!
self.view.addSubview(testButton)

self.testButton.target = self
self.testButton.action = #selector(ViewController.printSomething)
```

Update : The testButton is not clickable after a `CATransform`

```
self.infosView.layer?.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(500, 0, 0)
```

Doesn't work after this..

Comment: Does it work if you remove the custom class from `infosView` in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I paste here the answer of this question. The problem was the constraints of the NSView.

1- Create a NSLayoutConstraints() variable

2- Set the constraints of the NSView

```
self.infosView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.leadingConstraint = self.infosView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: -500)
        self.leadingConstraint.isActive = true
        self.infosView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.infosView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0, constant: 500).isActive = true
        self.infosView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0, constant: (NSScreen.main?.frame.height)!).isActive = true
```

3 - Then when I want to update the NSView which contains the NSButton

```
self.leadingConstraint.constant = 0

runAnimation(duration: 0.5, {
    self.testButton.superview?.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()

    self.infosViewOpened = true

})
```